# In iOS how can I remove languages from Localizable.strings with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

This is how my xcode project looks.  I would like to remove the Localizable.strings for UK and US and just keep the Localizable.strings for English.  How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the instructions in the image below

[image]

Comment: great tip !  that's in the "file inspector" ("right panel") by the way for anyone googling

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the specific files and delete them from the project. Just make sure that in the file inspector as well they are removed for the Localizable.strings.